# Access the last file (alphabetically) in a directory

Tags: command-line, terminal

I'm trying to open a file with vim from the command line, the file is in a directory filled with automatically generated files that are prepended with a time stamp.  Since I don't know the time stamps off the top of my head, I would just like to open the most recent one in the directory (also the last one in the list alphabetically).

```
vim ./my_dir/<last_item>
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: People are assuming that your operating system has POSIX-conformant utilities and shells.  You haven't given that information, though.  Does your operating system have POSIX-conformant shells and utilities?  Tag your question _properly_.  (Terminals have nothing to do with this.)

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
vim my_dir/$(ls my_dir | tail -n 1)
```

How it works:

1. Since the result is piped, `ls` displays one bare file name per line.
2. `tail -n 1` only shows the last line.
3. `$(...)` executes the command and appends the output to `vim mydir/`.

Comment: just a small tip, you don't need `-1` passed to `ls` in this situation; `ls` chooses that output format since you use a pipe. To both @Dennis and @Lee, this is harder than it sounds, what if the last object is a directory? You can have simple, or you can have solid, not both.

Comment: @RichHomolka: Thank you for the tip. I have updated my answer. Regarding your objection, a simple `--group-directories-first` should take care of directories.